# My air conditioner is making noises

Tags: ford, ac, noise, taurus

Can the air conditioner be unhooked and not affect the rest of the car? It's a 2006 Ford Taurus

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What kind of noise does it make? Does it make the noise if the A/C is on (running) or not?

Comment: A rattle when not and a louder noise when it's running.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I asked you what kind of noise the car was making and when it's making it, is because depending on when it makes the noise, you might have gotten by with leaving the A/C compressor in place and just not energizing it. From you description and follow-up comment, it would seem to me your compressor clutch and/or the compressor itself is bad (making noise whether on or off). Unfortunately the serpentine belt rides on the pulley which is part of the clutch. To "disconnect" the A/C compressor, you'd need to remove it completely from the vehicle.

The following is what your serpentine belt routing should look like (as long as you're running a 3.0l engine and the internet isn't lying to me!):

[image]

Pulley #3 is where your A/C compressor is at. There is no way to just remove it without putting something else in it's place. There are some places which might sell a replacement idler pulley which would go in place of the A/C compressor. If you can find one, this would be your only choice besides replacing the compressor itself.